# ¿Como crear figuras con CSS y HTML?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando crear una portada con CSS como la que se muestra en la figura de abajo pero no logro hacer que los triangulos se vean redondeados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahorita, el div portada contiene la imagen de fondo.

```css
.div-portada {
    background-image: url('../../../assets/strength-people-hands.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}

.triangle-orange {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 600px solid transparent;
    border-right: 600px solid transparent;
    border-top: 600px solid #ff8c12;
}

.triangle-white {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.triangle-white:before {
    border-left: 500px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: 500px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -130px;
    width: 0;
    top: -138px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid div-portada" id="page1">
<div class="row mb-5">
   <div class="offset-3 col-9">
      <div class="triangle-orange"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-8">
      <div class="triangle-white">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por que ```triangle-orange``` no tiene dimensiones?

Comment: Me parece haber visto una pregunta con la misma foto, bueno, una manera simple que creo que podría resultar es usar border-radius en los elementos para el redondeado, y como son rectangulos o cuadrados los giras con rotate y los ocultas la mirad con un top o right negativo para que parezca triangulo.

Comment: Quizas te vendria bien hechar un vistazo a la etiqueta <SVG>

Comment: @ArnauCastellví gracias por la recomendación si me sirve pero no puedo agregar svg necesito css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al usar las propiedades `border`, no puedes redondearlas, entonces una solución es ver tu triangulo como un cuadrado o rectangulo inclinado. También podrías usar svg para dibujar ese tipo de figuras. Un ejemplo de lo primero mencionado sería así:

```css
.container{
 position:relative;
 top:-70px;
 width:100%;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 
}
.triangle{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:orange;
  border-radius:10px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```